# Moving FederatedEmail/SystemMailbox from One Store to Another - Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration

Just upgraded from Exchange 2003 to 2010. Somehow, I have two mailbox databases on my single Exchange 2010 server. One database contains all of the mailboxes I had moved from the 2003 exchange server; the other contains two SystemMailboxes and one FederatedEmail box.

I am just starting to get a grasp on the commands used in the EMS. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to move these three "system" mailboxes into my actual mailbox database so I can eliminate the second database.

Just trying to sure up this one server before I role out my backup Exchange server. Thanks in advance! Your help and ideas are greatly appreciated as I try to make this setup as simple as possible.

Comment: Here is the actual error message if I try to delete the store:
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.AssociatedUserMailboxExistException: This mailbox database contains one or more mailboxes or arbitration mailboxes. To get a list of all mailboxes in this database, run the command Get-Mailbox -Database <Database ID>. To get a list of all arbitration mailboxes in this database, run the command Get-Mailbox -Database <Database ID> -Arbitration. Before you can remove this mailbox database, you must disable, move, or remove user mailboxes and move arbitration mailboxes.

Comment: Upgraded = Transitioned.  
I tried "get-mailbox -database "Mailbox Database 0618761717"  -arbitration" and got:  
SystemMailbox{1f05a927... SystemMailbox{1f0... <server> unlimited  
SystemMailbox{e0dc1c29... SystemMailbox{e0d... <server>    unlimited  
FederatedEmail.4c1f4d8... FederatedEmail.4c... <server>    1 MB  

The mailbox does not contain any mailboxes if -Arbitration is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at work to verify this, but you can move them the same way you do any other mailbox using EMS as long as you can see them using "-Arbitration".  You can check out the page [here](http://blog.chrislehr.com/2009/10/exchange-2010-what-is-arbitration.htm), but the command is basically this:

```
Get-Mailbox -Arbitration -Database db1 | New-MoveRequest -TargetDatabase db2
```

You should probably run just the Get-Mailbox for the database to make sure it only displays the mailboxes you want to move because I can't verify the command at the moment.

Comment: Worked exactly as you stated. Thank you very much!